# DataFrame Pandas update formula

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have the following DataFrame:

```
ds = pd.DataFrame(np.abs(randn(3, 4)), index=[1,2,3], columns=['A','B','C','D'])

ds
      A         B         C         D
1  1.099679  0.042043  0.083903  0.410128
2  0.268205  0.718933  1.459374  0.758887
3  0.680566  0.538655  0.038236  1.169403
```

and I would like to add a column E such that `ds['E'] = row_sum(ds['A'],ds['B'])`

and if one of the values in columns 'A' or 'B' is changed 'E' is updated automatically (similar to Excel)

Comment: I don't think it would work that way but for simple formulas like that it would be very fast to recompute the values, also you shouldn't think that a dataframe is comparable to an excel spreadsheet where you can bind a function to other cells in the dataframe

Comment: My "real question" was about a situation where there are large number of columns and then the recomputing time may increase significantly

Comment: Still there is no automatic updating of a column just because it's based on calculations on another column, you'd have to add some code to handle this

Comment: Can you give an example, let take the simplest instance of DataFrame df with two columns A,B and we want to add a new column C such that C = A+B and C will be updated automatically each time the values in A or B change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible to add computed columns, but you can always create a function:

```
def ds_e(ds):
    return row_sum(ds['A'],ds['B'])
```

which is basically the same :)

Comment: My point was that creating such function is simple, what I wanted was to assign a formula to new column 'E' such that any change  in the values of the variables of the formula will also change the column 'E' with no need to call this function again

Comment: you can just use function instead of column. It's not the same, but close

Comment: The thing is that if you want to create a new column 'F' with a formula that is based on 'E' adding a function will complicate the code